# Remove Components from Windows 10 like ntlite does

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I only started to program c++ half a year ago, and would be so happy if you could just help me out by giving me a point to start with.

I want to understand how ntlite removes drivers from the iso.
I want to know what do I need to learn/know/read about to program
a tool myself that removes stuff like that. For example the w-lan drivers
or Cortana.

By researching I came across:

- the windows registry
- powershell

...and that's it. Nothing like "learn the powershell to tweak your system tutorial" and before I start reading a book about these topics, I wanted to know if it is the right way to achieve my goal?

I am sorry if my question is unwelcome or stupid. I just want to learn about
these things and can't find the right way to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are wanting to customize your windows image using PowerShell, dism has always worked well for me. Here is some [documentation from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/?view=win10-ps)

Comment: This is off topic for [so] as it's not a direct issue with code, voting to move to [sf] where windows admin issues like this are better suited.

Comment: My best best is try to install the software, and decompile it in order to check what exactly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove elements from Windows, you can do that using the `Add-WindowsOptionalFeature` and `Remove-WindowsOptionalFeature` PowerShell Cmdlets.

Let's say you wanted to remove the new Calc.exe and return to the old, *correct* Calc.exe app.

You can do that in your running Windows Instance using this command (when running PowerShell as an Administrator)

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online  -FeatureName "Calc" -PackageName
"Microsoft.Windows.Calc.Demo~6595b6144ccf1df~x86~en~1.0.0.0"
```

If you wanted to remove it from a Windows Image instead, first you have to mount the Windows image by mounting `install.wim` from the disc using the `Mount-WindowsImage` cmdlet, like this.

```
Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath "c:\imagestore\install.vhd" -Index 1 -Path "c:\offline"
```

This would mount the image to your c:\Offline folder.  The folder needs to exist first, BTW.

Next, to disable the feature in the Windows Image.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Path "c:\offline" -FeatureName "Calc" -PackageName
"Microsoft.Windows.Calc.Demo~6595b6144ccf1df~x86~en~1.0.0.0" -Remove
```

When that's done, you save the changes using:

```
Dismount-WindowsImage -Path "c:\offline" -Save
```

NtLite and these PowerShell tools all use the Deployment Image Servicing Manager tool, DISM, and its C# libraries to actually enact the changes.  If you want to know more, [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism) this and [this](https://www.cio.com/article/3028977/windows/why-dism-is-the-swiss-army-knife-of-windows-10-maintenance.html).

Comment: my hero of day! Thank you so much, And everybody else who answered! Now i know what to do! THank you SIr!